# найти одинаковые ключи объектов в разных массивах

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть 2 массива объектов, нужно найти совпадения ключей, перемножить их значения и вернуть новый массив получившихся в результате умножения чисел

```
    const alphabet = [
        { key: 'a', value: 1 },
        { key: 'b', value: 2 },
        { key: 'c', value: 3 },
        { key: 'd', value: 4 },
        { key: 'e', value: 5 },
        { key: 'f', value: 6 },
        { key: 'g', value: 7 },
        { key: 'h', value: 8 },
        { key: 'i', value: 9 },
        { key: 'j', value: 10 },
        { key: 'k', value: 11 },
        { key: 'l', value: 12 },
        { key: 'm', value: 13 },
        { key: 'n', value: 14 },
        { key: 'o', value: 15 },
        { key: 'p', value: 16 },
        { key: 'q', value: 17 },
        { key: 'r', value: 18 },
        { key: 's', value: 19 },
        { key: 't', value: 20 },
        { key: 'u', value: 21 },
        { key: 'v', value: 22 },
        { key: 'w', value: 23 },
        { key: 'x', value: 24 },
        { key: 'y', value: 25 },
        { key: 'z', value: 26 },
    ],
arrValue = [{ key: 'a', value: 3 },
        { key: 'b', value: 4 },
        { key: 'c', value: 3 },
        { key: 'd', value: 3 }]
```

Comment: Новый массив (который нужно вернуть) должен состоять только из тех элементов которые совпадают?

Comment: да, именно из ключей перемноженных, в данном примере 1*3,  4*2, 3*3, 4*3 и должно получиться [3, 8, 9, 12]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как один из вариантов.

```
function foo(arr1,arr2){ /////Передаём 2 массива
    let resArr = []; //// создаём массив который в будущем выведем
    arr1.forEach((obj1)=>{ /// перебираем первый массив 
        arr2.forEach((obj2)=>{ ///перебираем второй массив
            if(obj1.key == obj2.key){ /// сравниваем "ключи" из объектов
                resArr.push({key:obj1.key,value:obj1.value*obj2.value}); ///вставляем в наш созданный массив объект типа {key:'ключ',value:'перемноженное число'}
            }
        })
    })
    return resArr;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, это то, что я искал